# NLog Configuration - SMTP Email Notifications are not working

Tags: email, smtp, nlog

I have configured NLog Configuration to send an email to the admin user when an error is occurred. The SMTP configuration in the config file looks as below:

```
<target xsi:type="Mail"
    name="MailLogTarget" 
    header="&lt;p&gt;Hello,&lt;/p&gt;"
        html="true"
    subject="Layer 2 Sync Error – ${event-context:ThreadContextIdentifier}"
    body="&lt;p&gt;Error during synchronization for project: ${event-context:ThreadContextIdentifier}&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; Error: ${message}&lt;/p&gt;"
    from="xxxx@xxxx.com"
    to="xxxx@xxxx.com"
    smtpUserName="xxxx@xxxx.com"
    smtpPassword="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    smtpAuthentication="Basic"
    smtpServer="smtp.office365.com"
    smtpPort="587"
    enableSsl="true"
/>
```

This works fine in the development environment, however, this does not work in the production environment. We have verified, no ports are blocked on the production environment for sending the email, so this is not a network issue.

Requesting for help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest sending any email programmatically in the production using your credentials. Does it work correctly?

Comment: [Remember to flush](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#5-remember-to-flush)  and check the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging)